# how can I add a command for my app to rerun

Tags: button, applescript

I'm trying to get the app to "rerun" when the "return to formula list" button is pushed.

I thought this would work since I basically have it going back to the main list, but once it gets back to the list and another selection is made, it exits the app. this obviously isn't the whole code, I just included the first two options.

```
--DIVE FORMULAS--
--RUN FORMULA LIST--
set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free Gas Volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Partial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"})

--DIVERS CONSUMPTION AT DEPTH--
if x is "Divers consumption at depth" then

--VARIABLES--
display dialog "What is divers breathing volume (L/min) (default 35 l/min?" default answer "35"
set varDvol to text returned of result
display dialog "What is divers absolute depth pressure (bar)" default answer ""
set varPbar to text returned of result

--FORMULA--
set answer to varDvol * varPbar

--ANSWER--
display dialog "A diver breathing " & varDvol & " l/min, at an absolute pressure of " & varPbar & " bar, will have a consumption of " & answer & " l/min" as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to formula list", "Exit"}

--OPTIONS--
set response to button returned of result

--SEE FORMULA--
if response = "See formula" then
    display dialog "Divers Consumption = Divers Breathing Volume * Absolute pressure of depth (bar)" buttons ("Return to Formula List")

    --RETURN TO FORMULA LIST--
    set response to button returned of result
    if response = "Return to Formula List" then
        set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free gas volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Prartial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"})
    end if

    --RETURN TO FORMULA LIST--
else if response = "Return to formula list" then
    set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free gas volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Prartial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"})

    --EXIT APP--
else if response = "Exit" then
    display dialog "Are you sure you wish to exit?" buttons {"Return to Formula List", "Exit"}
    set response to button returned of result
    if response = "Return to Formula List" then
        set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free gas volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Prartial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"})
    end if
else if response = "EXIT" then
    quit
end if



--FREE GAS VOLUME--
else if x is "Free gas volume (FGV)" then

--VARIABLES--
display dialog "What is the floodable volume of the cylinder (L)?" default answer ""
set varFvol to text returned of result
display dialog "What is the pressure of the cylinder (bar)?" default answer ""
set varCylPress to text returned of result

--FORMULA--
set answer to varFvol * varCylPress

--ANSWER--
display dialog "The free gas volume is (L)" & answer as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to formula list", "Exit"}

--OPTIONS--
set response to button returned of result

--SEE FORMULA--
if response = "See formula" then
    display dialog "FGV = Floodable volume of cylinder * Pressure of cylinder (bar)"

    --RETURN TO FORMULA LIST--
else if response = "Return to formula list" then
    set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free gas volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Partial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"})

    --EXIT APP--
else if response = "Exit" then
    #do a third thing
end if
```

like I said, the "return to formula list" button works, but when I make another choice from the main list, the app closes, it won't go on to the next chosen function, which is what I'm looking for

Comment: Unrelated but be aware that an error is thrown if the `Cancel` button is pressed in all `choose from list` lines

Comment: I don't even want the cancel button on there, is there a way to get rid of it?? I just want an ok button

Comment: No, the buttons of `choose from list` are hard-coded.

Comment: You should look into the use of handlers (subroutines), otherwise your script is going to get busy and hard to follow/debug as you implement (or add to) the other options.

Comment: yea, I'm starting to run into that now lol, luckily its a whole lot of copy and paste and the codes for majority of it are the same since its just doing math and changing the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you…

Anywhere in your code you see this...

```
if response = "Return to Formula List" then
    set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free gas volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Prartial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"})
end if
```

Try replacing it with this...

```
if response = "Return to Formula List" then
    run me
end if
```

Comment: @PaulBrann Glad I was able to help. If you find my answer was the best solution to your question, please mark it as the accepted answer and or upvote it please.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the use of handlers (subroutines), otherwise you are going to get lost fairly quickly as you implement the other options or expand features in the script.

One way you can do this is by restructuring the script, putting the main list into a repeat statement, and having each choice run in a separate handler.  These handlers would only be concerned with their specific function (also handy for viewing and debugging), and could return the button of the last dialog for the main loop to use, for example:

```
on run -- main
    repeat -- forever
        set choice to (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free Gas Volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Partial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"} cancel button name "Exit") as text — just one item
        if choice is "Divers consumption at depth" then
            set theResult to consumption()
        else if choice is "Free Gas Volume (FGV)" then
            set theResult to volume()
        else if choice is "Cylinder Duration" then
            set theResult to duration()
        else if choice is "Partial Pressure" then
            set theResult to pressure()
        else if choice is "Initial Depth" then
            set theResult to depth()
        else if choice is "Cylinder Mixing" then
            set theResult to mixing()
        end if
        if choice is "false" or theResult is "Exit" then -- exit
            set response to (display dialog "Are you sure you wish to exit?" buttons {"Return to Formula List", "Exit"})
            if button returned of response is "Exit" then exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end run

on consumption() -- Divers consumption at depth
    --VARIABLES--
    set response to (display dialog "What is divers breathing volume (L/min) (default 35 l/min?" default answer "35" buttons {"Exit", "OK"} default button 2)
    if button returned of response is "Exit" then return "Exit"
    set varDvol to text returned of response
    set response to (display dialog "What is divers absolute depth pressure (bar)" default answer "1" buttons {"Exit", "OK"} default button 2)
    if button returned of response is "Exit" then return "Exit"
    set varPbar to text returned of response

    --FORMULA--
    set answer to varDvol * varPbar

    --ANSWER--
    set response to (display dialog "A diver breathing " & varDvol & " l/min, at an absolute pressure of " & varPbar & " bar, will have a consumption of " & answer & " l/min" as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to formula list", "Exit"})

    --SEE FORMULA--
    if button returned of response = "See formula" then
        set response to (display dialog "Divers Consumption = Divers Breathing Volume * Absolute pressure of depth (bar)" buttons {"Return to Formula List", "Exit"})
    end if
    return button returned of response
end consumption

on volume() -- Free Gas Volume (FGV)
    set response to (display dialog "volume" buttons {"Exit", "OK"} default button 2)
    return button returned of response
end volume

on duration() -- Cylinder Duration
    set response to (display dialog "duration" buttons {"Exit", "OK"} default button 2)
    return button returned of response
end duration

on pressure() -- Partial Pressure
    set response to (display dialog "pressure" buttons {"Exit", "OK"} default button 2)
    return button returned of response
end pressure

on depth() -- Initial Depth
    set response to (display dialog "depth" buttons {"Exit", "OK"} default button 2)
    return button returned of response
end depth

on mixing() -- Cylinder Mixing
    set response to (display dialog "mixing" buttons {"Exit", "OK"} default button 2)
    return button returned of response
end mixing
```

Comment: that def cleans it up, I assume that I would just add the formulas before the "end commands"

Comment: Yes, each `on whatever() … end whatever` is its own subroutine and would handle a single option in your list.  My example routines return the button of the last dialog so that you can use a button named “Exit” to confirm exiting the app without duplicating the code for the dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution, I think, is to enclose your code in a repeat loop, and let the repeat loop handle all of the 'return to list' actions. Then you can delete all the duplicate `choose from list` lines, and all you need to do is call `exit repeat` when you want to get out.

```
--DIVE FORMULAS--
--RUN FORMULA LIST--
repeat
    set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free Gas Volume (FGV)", "Cylinder Duration", "Partial Pressure", "Initial Depth", "Cylinder Mixing"})

    --DIVERS CONSUMPTION AT DEPTH--
    if x is "Divers consumption at depth" then

        --VARIABLES--
        display dialog "What is divers breathing volume (L/min) (default 35 l/min?" default answer "35"
        set varDvol to text returned of result
        display dialog "What is divers absolute depth pressure (bar)" default answer ""
        set varPbar to text returned of result

        --FORMULA--
        set answer to varDvol * varPbar

        --ANSWER--
        display dialog "A diver breathing " & varDvol & " l/min, at an absolute pressure of " & varPbar & " bar, will have a consumption of " & answer & " l/min" as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to formula list", "Exit"}

        set response to button returned of result

        --SEE FORMULA--
        if response = "See formula" then
            display dialog "Divers Consumption = Divers Breathing Volume * Absolute pressure of depth (bar)" buttons ("Return to Formula List")
        else if response = "Exit" then
            display dialog "Are you sure you wish to exit?" buttons {"Return to Formula List", "Exit"}
            set response to button returned of result
            if response = "exit" then
                exit repeat
            end if
        end if

        --FREE GAS VOLUME--
    else if x is "Free gas volume (FGV)" then

        --VARIABLES--
        display dialog "What is the floodable volume of the cylinder (L)?" default answer ""
        set varFvol to text returned of result
        display dialog "What is the pressure of the cylinder (bar)?" default answer ""
        set varCylPress to text returned of result

        --FORMULA--
        set answer to varFvol * varCylPress

        --ANSWER--
        display dialog "The free gas volume is (L)" & answer as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to formula list", "Exit"}

        --OPTIONS--
        set response to button returned of result

        --SEE FORMULA--
        if response = "See formula" then
            display dialog "FGV = Floodable volume of cylinder * Pressure of cylinder (bar)"                
            --EXIT APP--
        else if response = "Exit" then
            #do a third thing
        end if
    end if
end repeat
```

You don't need to explicitly call 'quit' unless your app is designed as a stay-open app. Once you exit the repeat loop and hit the last line of code, the app will automatically terminate.